# How can i understand this contradiction of $H^{-s}(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, finite-element-method

This makes me puzzled.Here $H^{k}(\Omega)$ is the sobolev space $W_p^k(\Omega)$ with $p=2$.

We all know that $H^{k}(\Omega)$ is Hilbert space,This means that $(H^k(\Omega))^{*}=H^{-k}(\Omega)$ should be $H^{k}(\Omega)$ itself from Risez Representation theorem.

However,we know that Dirac $\delta$-function $\delta\in W^{k}_p(\Omega)$ if $k<-n+n/p \  $ from Sobolev's Inequality.Clearly $\delta\notin H^{k}(\Omega),\forall k>0$.This will be a contradiction,cause there are some $k$ such that $\delta\in H^{-k}(\Omega)$ while $\delta\notin H^{k}(\Omega)$.

What's wrong with my previous statement?

Answer (score 4):

This is a good question. A while ago, I was puzzled by this myself.

The apparent contradiction is resolved by noting that this is a problem of **choosing the right "dual pairing"**.

You have indeed $(H^s)^\ast = H^s$, if you identify a function $f \in H^s$ with the functional $g \mapsto \langle g, f\rangle_{H^s} = \sum_{|\alpha|\leq s} \int \partial^\alpha g \overline{\partial^\alpha f}$ (or whatever scalar product you use on $H^s$).

On the other hand, when you write $\delta \in H^{-s}$, then you mean the functional $f \mapsto f(0)$. Essentially, what one uses here is the dual pairing from the (tempered) distributions, which extends the pairing $\langle f,g\rangle = \int f \overline{g}$.

The (perhaps surprising) consequence of this is that (by the Riesz representation theorem) there is a function $g \in H^s$ with $\delta(f) = \langle f,g\rangle_{H^s}$ for all $f \in H^s$.

Comment: Thank you,but i think it is hard to construct such a function in $H^{s}$,can you prove its existence or construct it?

Comment: @foxell: Well, its existence follows from Riesz representation theorem, once you know that $f \mapsto \delta(f)$ is a bounded linear functional on $H^s$. I am not sure at the moment if one can give a more explicit construction.

Comment: I have founded the construction,I think this may be helpful for you:http://roth.cs.kuleuven.be/w-ess/index.php/What_is_the_Dirac_delta_function_exactly%3F

Comment: @foxell Do you still have that document? The link appears broken.